# Можно ли в интерцепторах менять параметры запроса?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, get

Можно ли в интерцепторе менять параметры get запроса или заменять multipart file? У меня в контроллере очень много проверок параметров на пустоту и это выглядит просто чудовищно, можно ли как то вынести эту проверку отдельно и если допустим обнаружиться что параметр пустой присвоить ему значение "1".
 И так же с файлом, перед загрузкой картинки , в контроллере она сначала обрезается и масштабируется, можно ли как то обрезать её до контроллера и заменить файл в запросе?

И если можно, то правильно ли так делать???

Код выглядит примерно вот так. (Запрос для поиска, поэтому много параметров)

```
        String size = request.getParameter("size");

        String sort = request.getParameter("sort");

        String country = request.getParameter("country");

        String genre = request.getParameter("genre");


        if (country == null || country.isEmpty()) 
            country = "0";



        if (genre == null || genre.isEmpty()) 
            genre = "0";



        if (size == null || size.isEmpty()) 
            size = "40";

        if (sort == null || sort.isEmpty())
        sort = "id";
```

Comment: приведите код контроллера - что за "чудовищные" проверки там

Comment: сколько всего параметров?

Comment: @Nikolay всего 5 параметров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модифицировать запрос - неправильный подход.
Если в запросе нет обязательных параметров, либо параметры имеют недопустимые значения, то необходимо сообщить об этом клиенту (через http-код и/или сообщение об ошибке) и не обрабатывать этот запрос.
Если некоторые параметры могут иметь значения по умолчанию, то эти значения нужно опрделять в контроллере (при вызове методов сервисного слоя).
В вашем случае, судя по всему, в контроллере содержится очень много логики, что неверно - контроллер должен содержать минимум логики - урезание картинок должно производить в сервисе для работы с картинками и т.д. Контроллер принимает запрос, вызывает некоторые методы сервисного слоя и возврщает результат.
Если вас смущает большой код по проверке каждого параметра - то в вашем случае это легко рефаторится:

```
private static String getRequestParam(HttpServletRequest request, String name, String defaultValue){
    String value = request.getParameter(name);
    return StringUtils.hasText(value)? value: defaultValue;
}
```

И затем в контроллере:

```
String size = getRequestParam(request, "size", "0");
String sort = getRequestParam(request, "sort", "id");
String country = getRequestParam(request, "country", "0");
String genre = getRequestParam(request, "genre", "0");
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение!

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли в интерцепторе менять параметры get запроса или заменять multipart file?

Однозначно нет. Интерцептор не предназначен для изменения запроса. Вы можете использовать Filter вместо Интерцептора, однако применительно к вашему случаю это вряд ли можно считать хорошей практикой проектирования. По сути, вы хотите вытащить логику, по праву принадлежащую слою контроллеров, и спустить её на уровень ниже, где ей совсем не место. Короче, лучше уж в контроллере работать с параметрами, чем в фильтре ковыряться в запросе. А что касается "чудовищного кода" в контроллерах - решите это хорошим проектированием слоя контроллеров.